# kitchen terraform error - Could not load the 'terraform' driver. Error: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass

Tags: terraform, test-kitchen

I'm following https://newcontext-oss.github.io/kitchen-terraform/getting_started.html
However, when I try and run:
bundle exec kitchen converge

I get the following error:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ClientError
>>>>>> Message: Could not load the 'terraform' driver. Error: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Any ideas?
Running TF 1.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this bug too when following the official tutorial.

**I resolved it by updating the Gemfile to use the newest version of kitchen-terraform**

```
# Gemfile

source "https://rubygems.org/"
gem "kitchen-terraform", "6.0"
```

Let me know if it solved your problem!

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the issue.
Previously my Gemfile was included this:
ruby '2.6.8'

source "https://rubygems.org/" do
  gem "kitchen-terraform", "~> 5.8.0"
end

I have 5.8.0 and 6.0.0 installed so not sure why that wouldn't work so I tested your solution and that worked so I then uninstalled 5.8.0 and just changed it to :
ruby '2.6.8'

source "https://rubygems.org/" do
  gem "kitchen-terraform", ">= 5.8.0"
end

So that worked, presumably was an issue with a local conflict between the dependencies.